# Updating global variable value locally only in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I've a commun data in my application, and in some view I've to update those value only inside this view. 
So I've created a local variable inside this view, then I set the value of those variable equal to the global variable and finally I've updated those global variable. This is my code :

```
 if (_isCitySelector){
     _dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[Commun sharedInstance] stateArray]];
     _subDataArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[[Commun sharedInstance] cityDictionary]];
 } else {
     _dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[Commun sharedInstance] categoriesArray]];
     _subDataArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[[Commun sharedInstance] subCategoriesDictionary]];
 }
if (_activateParentSelection){
    for (PFObject *object in _dataArray) {
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = (NSMutableArray *)[_subDataArray valueForKey:object.objectId];
        if ([[tempArray objectAtIndex:0][@"titre"] isEqualToString: @"الكل"])
            continue;

        PFObject *tempObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:[object parseClassName]];
        tempObject[@"titre"] = @"الكل";
        if (object[@"nbrAnnonce"]){
            tempObject[@"categorie_id"] = object;
            tempObject[@"nbrAnnonce"] = @0;
        }else
            tempObject[@"region_id"] = object;

        [tempArray insertObject:tempObject atIndex:0];
        [_subDataArray setObject:tempArray forKey:object.objectId];
    }
}
```

This code work's fine, but the problem this will update the global variable also ? what's wrong in my code !!!

**Update** 
I can't use `copyWithZone` because my data type is `PFObject` and parse.com object doesn't support this function

Comment: Try this! `NSMutableArray *tempArray = [(NSMutableArray *)[_subDataArray valueForKey:object.objectId] mutableCopy]`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this init method for the array:

```
NSArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[Commun sharedInstance] stateArray] copyItems:YES];
```

This will create a separate copy of your data.

Comment: I can't use copyItems because copyWithZone is not defined in my class ( I'm using Parse object )